# How do I create function to generate plot for each column

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, apply

here is an example dataset:

```
Group<-c("Blue","Red","Green","Blue","Red","Green")
UV<-c("3","4","2","5","4","6")
Rain<-c("10","11","12","15","16","17")

dmean<-data.frame(Day,Group,UV,Rain)

Day<-c("1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","2","2",)
Group<-c("Blue","Blue","Red","Red","Green","Green","Blue","Blue","Red","Red","Green","Green")
UV<-c("3","3.1","4","4.1","2","2.2","5","5.1","4","4.2","6.1","6.1")
Rain<-c("10","10.1","11","11","12","12.2","15","15.2","16","16.1","17","17.2")

dpoints<-data.frame(Day,Group,UV,Rain)
```

Basically, I have a large dataset with multiple variables, in this example here,"UV" and "Rain" which I group by "Day" and "Group". I want to generate a plot for each column, eg "UV" and "Rain" using geom line to connect the mean values from "dmean", together with the data points in "dpoints" using a function as below which may not be right and incomplete:

```
plot.ts <- function(d){
  
  ggplot(dmean, aes(x = Day, y = col.num+2, group = Group, colour = Group)) +
    geom_line(size = 1)+
    geom_point(dpoints, aes(y = d0[,col.num+2]),
               alpha = .2) +
    facet_wrap(~Group, 
               ncol = 1) +
    ggsave(paste0("plot1_",col.num,".png"), width = 15, height = 10, dpi = 300, units = "in", device='png')
  
}
```

Here is an example figure for "UV" which I hope to generate along with other variables too.
[image]
Could someone please check through the function and apply the function through the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve y<our desired result you have to do some adjustments on your function. First I make `plot.ts` a function which takes one argument, that name of the column to be mapped on `y`. Second, inside `ggplot()` I make use of the `.data` pronoun from the `rlang` package which allows to use a column name as a string in `ggplot`. Afterwards you could use `lapply` to loop over a list of your desired columns to create your plots:

```r
library(ggplot2)

plot.ts <- function(yvar) {
  ggplot(dmean, aes(x = Day, y = .data[[yvar]], group = Group, colour = Group)) +
    geom_line(size = 1)+
    geom_point(data = dpoints, aes(y = .data[[yvar]]), alpha = .2) +
    facet_wrap(~Group, ncol = 1) +
    labs(title = yvar)
    #ggsave(paste0("plot1_",col.num,".png"), width = 15, height = 10, dpi = 300, units = "in", device='png')
}

lapply(c("UV", "Rain"), plot.ts)
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

Comment: If I have multiple variables (yvar) to apply plot.ts function on say from column 3 to column 30 of  "dmean", how do I avoid naming the variables one by one  in  " lapply(c("UV", "Rain"), plot.ts)"?

Comment: You could do `lapply(names(dmean)[3:30], plot.ts)`

Comment: That's a very neat solution, Thanks!